# Can one detect, via the AWS RDS API, any I/O suspension when creating a snapshot for a single-AZ DB instance?

Tags: amazon-rds, snapshot

This is *very* similar to this existing question:

- [amazon web services - RDS snapshot: how long does I/O suspension occur? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/919533/rds-snapshot-how-long-does-i-o-suspension-occur)

Unfortunately, the only answer provides more of a background about *why* a suspension is required/inevitable and neither answers that question more specifically nor provides any details sufficient to answer *this* question.

What I'd like to do is:

1. Disable all of the applications using a specific RDS instance.
2. Initiate creating a snapshot for the RDS instance.
3. Detect when any I/O suspension has ended.
4. Re-enable all of the applications using the RDS instance.

Is there a way to do [3] via the AWS RDS API? Could I, for instance, check the RDS instance status (and test that it's `'available'`)?

Comment: you can use DBInstanceStatus from aws rds describe-db-instances

Comment: @John Yes, that's what I was thinking – I mentioned it in my question. But I haven't found any AWS docs stating that. So far, from testing, the I/O suspension is apparently so brief that the instance is effectively instantly `'available'`.

Comment: I think the best you can do here is an experiment. BTW do not trust 100% RDs docs, I already found some places where it is not correct

Comment: @John That's definitely where I'm at now. So far, the I/O suspension, if there is any, is too brief to detect, using the status NOT being `'available'` as a proxy for any suspension. That's good, if the proxy is accurate.